# Joomla : Define an access when an user is not into an users group

Tags: joomla

Imagine the situation

To purchase on a site, a customer must to register himself before order an item. In this case all customers of the site are users registered (group1).

With that site, you can buy items but also subscriptions to enable the reading of some articles of the site. When a customer purchases a subscription, he is automatically set into another group of users (group2) to enable the reading of those articles. Those customers are both in group1 and group2.

In short

Group1 : All customers

Group2 : Customers with right to read some articles

Note that the users of group2 are also member of the group1 because they are customers.

Now the site would like to display some modules to encourage the purchase of a subscription. These modules should be displayed to site visitors (guest group) and customers of the site without a subscription.

Create an access level for the guest group and for the group of customers (group1) is not good because when a member of the group2 will connect to the site, he will see theses modules.

I would like to create an access level for the public (guest group) and for customers but which are not part of group2.

Perhaps it is really easy but immediatly I do not see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Those users are in the group guest. So assign the module to the guest group.

Comment: That's right for the public but not for the registered users.

I tried to be much clear.

When an user is registered on the site, he is registered in the group of registered users (for example group1).

Furthermore, some users of the group1 are also registered in another group (for example group2).

I would like to create an access for the public but also for the users of the group1 but not for the users of the group2.

Comment: You make a visibility level (viewing access level) that is assigned to both guest and group1 and don't include group2.  Assign that viewing level to the module in question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I'm sorry it doesn't work because when an user from the group 2 connects to the site, the access of the module is enabled because that user is also into the group 1 (all registered users)

Comment: At this time, the only solution I found is to create a plugin system and on the onAfterModuleList event, remove the module of the list of the modules if the connected user is member of the group 2. Of course it work fine but I would like an easier solution if it was possible.

Comment: You need to make a separate group in that case. It's to really "all registered users" so you probably want to give it a new name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I 'm not sure to understand because I have already that group with all registered users, in my example it is the group1. I have changed my question to try to be much clear

Comment: You need to create a group that is ~group2 in other words you need a third group. When someone gets assigned to group2 you need to take them out of the ~group2 group. Guests should also get assigned to that group.  Since you must have some mechanism where you are assigning registered users to group2 at the same time you should take them out of the ~group2 group.

Comment: Thank for your solution and I think I understand it.

I think a third group (group3) could be a right solution but it is not an easy solution (see explanation below).

In fact, now I believe that it is a easy issue but there is no easy solution and for my opinion the only way to do that is by code (system or user plugin).

Comment: In my configuration, the group1 is the group that users are assigned to by default when they register on the site (I do nothing, it is automatic). If I use a third group, at the recording of a user on the site I should also set this user into the group3. After when an user has assigned into the group2, I should take out this user of the group3. But to assign users to the group3 at the recording, there is no automatic solution, so I should create an user plugin. It is not really difficult to create an user plugin but I have allready a solution with a plugin (see my comment above).